# How to click automatically submit button after selecting dropdownlist value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my code.
How to click automatically submit button after selecting dropdownlist value?

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="GET" name="form1" class="style1" id="form1">
  <p align="center">Select Section 
    <select name="section" required ><option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Section</option>
    <option>ALL</option>
    <option>RWS</option>
    <option>Structure</option></select>
    From
    <input name="fromdate" type="date" placeholder="YYYY-DD-MM" required id="mydate" data-lang="en" data-years="2014-2050" data-format="YYYY-MM-DD"/>
    To   
  <input name="todate" type="date" placeholder="YYYY-DD-MM" required id="mydate1" data-lang="en" data-years="2015-2055" data-format="YYYY-MM-DD"/>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="SHOW" />
  </p>
```

Comment: Need more information on the code.  Can't help without knowing more about the situation

Answer (score 2):

You will need to bind onchange event and call submit method of the HTMLFormElement:

```
$('#form1 select').on('change', function() {
    this.form.submit();
});
```

Important detail. Rename your submit button, you don't want it to have name `submit` because `this.form.submit` will point to HTMLButtonElement object in this case, while you want it to be a submit methods of the form element:

```
<input name="submit-btn" type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="SHOW" />
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/vkadz4cu/

Comment: After changing name of the button as suggested by you, nothing is happening, before name change I am getting results, after no results even i click the button

Comment: Check updated answer for working demo. After chaning button name and id make sure you update references in javascript.

Comment: is there any script to trig the button I mean I want o use onchange event for DD List

Comment: Hi dfsq I am not going to submit the form, I want to trig (click) SHOW button after value changed in dropdown list

Comment: Is there a click event bound to this button you want to trigger?

Comment: if possible i can add event, but i think adding event to DD List will trig the button, so want script or ajax function to trig the SHOW button, after trig the button this will pass the statement to sql query

Comment: Your button is submit button, it submits the form.

Comment: You are right it submit the form see the form action

Answer (score 0):

You have not given dropdown code here, hence I am assuming and writing:

```
<select name="drpdwn" onclick="submitForm()">
   <option value="opt1">Option1</        option>
 <option value="opt2">Option2</option>
 </option>

 <script>
 function submitForm(){
              document.getElementById('formid').submit();

   }


   </script>
```

Comment: <select name="section" required ><option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Section</option>
    <option>ALL</option>
    <option>RWS</option>                      I am not submitting the form, iwant to trig SHOW button after select the vale in DD List
    <option>Structure</option></select>

Comment: <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="GET" name="form1" class="style1" id="form1">
  <p align="center">Select Section 
    <select name="section" required ><option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Section</option>
    <option>ALL</option>
    <option>RWS</option>
    <option>Structure</option></select>
    From
    <input name="fromdate" type="date" placeholder="YYYY-DD-MM" required id="mydate" data-lang="en" data-years="2014-2050" data-format="YYYY-MM-DD"/>

Comment: To   
  <input name="todate" type="date" placeholder="YYYY-DD-MM" required id="mydate1" data-lang="en" data-years="2015-2055" data-format="YYYY-MM-DD"/>
  <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="SHOW" />
  </p>

Comment: is there any script to trig the button I mean I want o use onchange event for DD List

Comment: where is the jQuery Code??

Comment: onchange='JavaScript:jQuery("submit").trigger("click")'

Answer (score 0):

Seem you want to trigger event click on the button.

```
$('#form1 select').on('change', function() {
    $('#submit').trigger('click');
});
```